# Python - Reading the indices of pickled data

Tags: python, indexing, iteration, pickle

Having the following pickled data:

```
[array([[[148, 124, 115],
        [150, 127, 116],
        [154, 129, 121],
        ..., 
        [159, 142, 133],
        [159, 142, 133],
        [161, 145, 142]]]), array([1])]
```

I was able to retrieve the `data` and `label`, as follows:

```
data = batch[0]
labels = batch[1]
```

In which case, I had the following output when making a `print` for both data and label, separately:

```
[[[148 124 115]
  [150 127 116]
  [154 129 121]
  ...,
  [159 142 133]
  [159 142 133]
  [161 145 142]]]
[1]
```

When my batch file now looks as follows as I added a new image, I didn't figure out how to read the 2nd image and its label. It seems I cannot understand how the pickled file is indexed here:

```
[array([[[148, 124, 115],
        [150, 127, 116],
        [154, 129, 121],
        ..., 
        [159, 142, 133],
        [159, 142, 133],
        [161, 145, 142]],

       [[165, 136, 145],
        [176, 137, 141],
        [178, 138, 144],
        ..., 
        [199, 163, 171],
        [202, 163, 167],
        [200, 158, 163]]]), array([1, 1])]
```

How can I iterate through such pickled file? How is the file indexed? Especially that I would like to add more images along with their labels.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `all_data = batch[0]; second_image = all_data[1]`?

Comment: It appears that you second image is pickled in with your first image. Have you tried batch[0][0] for the first image and batch[0][1] for the second image?

Comment: @jfish003 It seems this would return the images. How would I return their labels?

Comment: The labels should then be batch[1][0] and batch[1][1]

Comment: @jfish003 Yes, seems that worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, I am going to put in an answer, for those who don't read the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your data is pickled, the two images end up in the same array and thus you have to index accordingly:

```
batch[0][0] #this will give the first image
batch[0][1] #this will give the second image
batch[1][0] #this will give the first label
batch[1][1] #this will give the second label
```